# Переименование поля во всем классе с JavaParser

Tags: java, парсер

Добрый день!
Необоходимо переименовать поле во всем классе с помощью **JavaParser**. 
Пример:
Есть код:

```
public class Test extends AbstractProcessCommand {

/*comment*/
private String name;

private void useName(){
    this.name = "someName";
}}
```

Необходимо получить:

```
public class Test extends AbstractProcessCommand {

/*comment*/
private String secondName;

private void useName(){
    this.secondName= "someName";
}}
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
private void editLocalField() throws IOException {
    CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(classFile.getFile());
    new EditLocalFieldVisitor().visit(cu, null);
    System.out.println(cu);
    classFile.writeFile(cu.toString());
}
private class EditLocalFieldVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter<Void> {
    @Override
    public void visit(FieldDeclaration n, Void arg) {
        if(n.getVariable(0).getName().asString().equals(fieldName)){
            n.getVariable(0).setName("secondName");
        }
    }
}
```

Но такой способ переименовывает не во всем классе, а только в строке объявление. Есть идеи? Заранее благодарен.